# boto3 s3 resource, bucket.objects.filter why is this so slow and takes so long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get the object list from a bucket I have that has probably billions of objects in it, in hundreds of folders, each with xx millions of objects.

The question I have is, why does using s3 resource.objects.filter take so long? And is there a way to use it and still get the same result as using client?

test results below

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3bucket = s3.Bucket("myBucket")
s3objects = s3bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder1/hello09_") # Also tried adding page_size(1000) no change
# folder1/ has xxx million objects
# folder1/hello09_ has xx million objects in it (ex. s3://myBucket/folder1/hello09_file0000001)

# takes about 21 minutes
tmp = [s3obj.key for s3obj in s3objects] 

# also takes about 20 minutes
tmp = []
   for s3obj in s3obj_list:
   tmp.append(s3obj.key)

# takes about 2 minutes
# wrote a s3client loop that gets 1000 files at a time
# client = boto3.client('s3')
# client.list_objects_v2(Bucket="myBucket",Prefix="folder1/hello09_")
# loop with NextContinuationToken until no more, 1000 objects each

# takes about 31 minutes
# same s3 client loop but this time changed the prefix to be only up to the deliminator
# The extra 10 minutes might be due to appending the results into an array, key by key?
# client = boto3.client('s3')
# client.list_objects_v2(Bucket="myBucket",Prefix="folder1/")
# loop with NextContinuationToken until no more, 1000 objects each
```

My best guess is that bucket.objects.filter queries ALL objects up to the last deliminator(folder1/) and THEN filters with whatever is after the last deliminator(hello09_). Instead of straight up querying the whole filter path(folder1/hello09_) like client does.

I thought resource was only querying 1 file at a time or something when used like an array or looped over instead of batch grabbing 1000 files from it (can you do that?). But I had a similar situation where I had dozens of subPrefixes each with 1 file in it, and resource.bucket.objects.filter performed the same as client.list_objects_v2.

Is this a bug in the boto3 filter code, or a feature that can be circumvented so resource can still be used with the same performance as client.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't know I could get such detailed logs, thanks Anon Coward.
So I guess I was wrong, it was sending the correct filtered request.
No idea how to read the log, but the various errors, retry requests, region redirectors, dns checks, etc are there. I don't think that those should cause the extra 18 minutes. But I have no idea anyways. Maybe some sort of background overhead work or prep of data so that it can be consumed? Vs Client where there are no errors.

Also no option to use S3 Inventory Report at the moment. Being too slow and not being realtime being one of problems.

So does that mean the only options are to use client? As S3 resource has some sort of internal efficiency or overhead problems when dealing with large number of objects, since it seems to work fine with small number of objects (same speed as client)?

I was hoping some sort of settings change could make resource as performant, but if its deep internal then maybe no go. Which is a shame considering how easy it is use Resource and not needing to manage multiple calls with continuationTokens.

```
botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=GET, 
url=https://myBucket.s3.xxxx.amazonaws.com/?prefix=myFolder1%2Fhello09_&encoding-type=url, 
headers={'User-Agent': b'Boto3/1.20.24 Python/3.8.0 Windows Botocore/1.27.59 Resource', 'X-Amz-Date': b'xxx', 
'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'xxx', 'Authorization': b'xxx', 'amz-sdk-invocation-id': b'xxx', 'amz-sdk-request': b'attempt=1'}>
...
botocore.parsers [DEBUG] Response headers: ...
...
[DEBUG] Event needs-retry.s3.ListObjects: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x000000????>
botocore.retryhandler [DEBUG] No retry needed.
```

**UPDATE2:**

Just for some closure I looked really closely at the http requests of both resource and client and there are differences. Resource does not specify which list, and uses markers instead of continuation Tokens, maybe S3 calculating where to continue from contributes to the slowness? Maybe the list method contributes to the slowness? (especially if list_objectsv1 is slower than v2 or harder to consume). Then there is what AnonCoward said, that resource inherently is slower because it performs more API calls and creates millions of (unneeded?) objects.

```
# client
url=https://myBucket.s3.xxx.amazonaws.com/
?list-type=2&
prefix=myFolder1%2Fhello_&
continuation-token=xxx
encoding-type=url,
```

```
# resource
url=https://myBucket.s3.xxx.amazonaws.com/
?
prefix=myFolder1%2Fhello_&
marker=myFolder1%2Fhello_world001&
encoding-type=url,
```

Comment: The filter operator should cause the proper prefix to be called.  You can verify this by turning on [full logging](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html) and see the API calls yourself.  That said, you will likely be much better off setting up an [S3 Inventory Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) and processing the data, rather than making tens of thousands of API calls.

Comment: @AnonCoward Tried looking at the logs, results look goods. So that means the problem is more internal to boto3 resource doesn't it....

Comment: In as much as there is a problem, yes, the resource methods are more memory and cpu intensive, so they'll take longer to parse through, create millions of objects, just so you can get the list of keys.  And costly as far as money spent on API calls.  It's doing a lot more work, so it takes more time.

Comment: If you have lots of objects, why not use S3 Batch processing?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the advice, but that requires a manifest list that comes from using S3 Inventory Report first. Admittedly using S3 Inventory Report sounds nice, but its not on the table at the moment. Realtime file listing from a subset of files inside the folder is what is needed. I have discovered the resource http request is different from the client request, I wonder if that is as intended or a bug/not yet updated.